# .offsetWidth not same when css padding is set (vs padding-left + padding-right)

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript that is trying to turn a container width from px to % based on the window width and the container width.

I have box-sizing set to border-box, but I don't think this matters in the logic.

I have a css of

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  xpadding:50px;            <---- padding:50px or xpadding:50px to see the difference
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To calculate the % width of the container, it should be just a case of running the following javascript:

```
const percentageWidth = ((containerWidth - totalMargin) / (windowWidth - totalBodyMargin - totalBodyPadding)) * 100;
container.style.width = percentageWidth + '%';
```

The result should be 100%, but for some reason if I have a css for body set to this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

... then it works (and results in 100%),

but if it's set to this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding:50px;    <------ added
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then it doesn't (resulting in 97.4818% [results will vary depending on the window width])

The odd thing here is that both situations claim the same padding, but different *container.offsetWidth* sizes:

a) width for container = 1040 + 200 = 98.39167455061495% when looking at a window width of 1257 - 0 - 200

vs

b) width for container = 1057 + 200 = 100% when looking at a window width of 1257 - 0 - 200

what goes on?

I have a jsfiddle for playing with on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/7c6k1f90/15/ and the same code can be found here....

*(note you need to adjust "xpadding:50px" on the css to "padding:50px" to see the different results)*

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const containerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(container);
const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
const totalMargin = parseFloat(containerStyles.marginLeft) + parseFloat(containerStyles.marginRight);

const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
const bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
const totalBodyPadding = parseFloat(bodyStyles.paddingLeft) + parseFloat(bodyStyles.paddingRight);
const totalBodyMargin = parseFloat(bodyStyles.marginLeft) + parseFloat(bodyStyles.marginRight);

const percentageWidth = ((containerWidth - totalMargin) / (windowWidth - totalBodyMargin - totalBodyPadding)) * 100;
container.style.width = percentageWidth + '%';
container.innerHTML+='<BR>container paddingLeft  = ' + bodyStyles.paddingLeft;
container.innerHTML+='<BR>container paddingRight =' + bodyStyles.paddingRight;
container.innerHTML+='<BR>width for container = '+containerWidth+ ' + ' + totalBodyPadding + ' = <b>' + percentageWidth + '%</b> when looking at a window width of '+windowWidth+' - '+ totalBodyMargin+' - ' + totalBodyPadding;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  xpadding:50px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: calc(100% - 0px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
</div>
```